# CSV DictReader only gets the first character of the CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I'm attempting to write a small python script that processes through CSV data. I read the URL and the data is there when I print the variable, but when I parse it using either csv.reader or csv.DictReader it only reads the first character as a field name and then the next character as the value for it. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong and I would appreciate the help.

Here's my code:

```
import sys
import os
import urllib2
import csv
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=YHOO&d=0&e=28&f=2010&g=d&a=3&b=12&c=2009&ignore=.csv')
html = response.read()
informed = csv.DictReader(html)

for row in informed:
  print row
```

which prints out a dictionary of ['D':'a'] for the first row, and all the rest are character pairs. Any help is appreciated. I'm using python 2.6 on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [csv module docs](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#module-contents), you need to pass a file or file-like object to the reader, not a string. I'm not familiar with what `urlopen` returns, but you could try passing `response` to the reader. Or, you could use a [StringIO object](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html) which is for just this purpose - `html = StringIO.StringIO(response.read())` ought to do it.

Comment: -1 `StringIO` is slower than `cStringIO` which is redundant anyway.  All you need is `for row_dict in csv.DictReader(response): do_something(row_dict)`

Comment: @JohnMachin - Thanks for the clarification on `response`. As I said in my answer, I'm not familiar with `urlopen`. And I didn't know about `cStringIO`, I've never had to use either of the string wrappers.

Comment: @mtrw: I'm not very familiar with `urllib2.urlopen` so I read the manual ("This function returns a file-like object") and actually tried what I was suggesting.

Answer (score -1):

why not just a regular `for` loop?

```
   response = urllib2.urlopen('http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=YHOO&d=0&e=28&f=2010&g=d&a=3&b=12&c=2009&ignore=.csv')
   for line in response.readlines():
        print line.split(',')
```

You already have the data as string, I don't understand why would you use csv module.

Comment: -1 (a) your code leaves a `\n` attached to the rightmost field (b) `.readlines()` is redundant (c) the OP wants a dict per row, not a list per row (d) even if you don't want a dict, and (as in this case) there are no *apparent* issues with commas, quotes and newlines in the data, using the csv module is faster, less code,  and more robust than any DIY hack.